# Change property of delegate on signal

Tags: qt, qml

I have a `TreeView`, and on the signal `onSortIndicatorChanged` I would like to set the `checked` property of a `CheckBox` inside the delegate of a `TableViewColumn` in my `TreeView`. However, I don't know how to do this.

```
Component {
  id: mycomp
  Item {
    id: myitm
    CheckBox {
      id: mycbx
      checked: true
    }
  }
}

TreeView {
  TableViewColumn {
    delegate: myDelegate
  }
  onSortIndicatorChanged{
    // set the checked property of the delegates to true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to add a property `checked` to your tree view and bind the check boxes to this property instead. Then, in the even handler, just set the value of the TreeView's property:

```
Component {
  id: mycomp
  Item {
    id: myitm
    CheckBox {
      id: mycbx
      checked: view.checked
    }
  }
}

TreeView {
    id: view

    property bool checked: false

    TableViewColumn {
        delegate: mycomp
    }
    onSortIndicatorChanged {
        view.checked = true
    }
}
```

**Update:**

In case you want to set a per-item checked state, you can use a similar approach where you store a function as a property of the view. In the delegate, you could call this stored function to get an item specific property value:

```
Component {
  id: mycomp
  Item {
    id: myitm
    CheckBox {
      id: mycbx
      checked: view.checkFunction ? view.checkFunction(modelData) : true
    }
  }
}

TreeView {
    id: view

    property var checkFunction: null

    TableViewColumn {
        delegate: mycomp
    }
    onSortIndicatorChanged {
        view.checkFunction = function(modelData) {
            // Calculate the checked state based on the modelData
            return modelData.foo == "bar";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is that the checked states for the different delegates can be different, depending on the result of a function. but for this I would also need to store the state in the model which I don't know how to do

Comment: Sorry, in this case I misunderstood your question. I updated my answer a bit - maybe you could check if this is applicable for you. There are other ways of solving your problem (like storing back the state in the model), however, the concrete answer would heavily depend on how your model looks like (e.g. QAbstractItemModel vs. QQmlListProperty vs. ...).

Comment: My model is a QFileSystemModel. Sorry for being so vague. Ideally I would like to store back to the model, as then I could store different values for different entries

Comment: I am not sure if with a QFileSystemModel you can actually store back this kind of "meta information". What you could do is either sub-class it and extend the `data()` and `setData()` methods (which you can then call from QML) or try with the stored function approach mentioned above. The latter has the advantage that you do not need to iterate over a potentially large list of files but the view would just need to call the stored function for the files that are currently visible. But again, the best way depends on what you actually try to do ;-)

Comment: if I bind the property of CheckBox to the result of a function, how does qt now when the checkFunction could lead to a different result, or asked differently: How can I update the delegate so it calls the function again?

Comment: The update is triggered by setting the property holding the function again. Basically, every time the `onSortIndicatorChanged` signal in the above example would get called, a new functor object will be created and assigned to the property. As a consequence, all (instantiated) objects created from your delegate will update themselves (as they notice the property value changed). That's the nice thing about the declarative approach with QML ;-)

Comment: Btw: If it helps, here is a minimal working [gist](https://gist.github.com/mhoeher/35e363368d3752319eb9b0ee803c4801) demonstrating the functor approach.